# Отступы по краям к TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

Добрый день. На картинке моя разметка.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сверху идет текст "55555" это TextView (растянут на всю ширину), а фон оранжевый это LinerLayout (растянут на всю ширину) у которого стоит фон оранжевый. Фон векторный конвертировала svg в xml drawable. Суть моей проблемы состоит в том, что на разных экранах эти оба компонента будут растягиваться и если в TextView будет больше текста (цифр), то этот текст будет накладываться на фон.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли универсальное решение, чтобы текст в TextView никогда не выходил за рамки этого фона, а скрывался вообще? Я пробовала сделать через padding, но мне кажется это не лучшее решение. Например на устройствах с 6-ти дюймовыми экранами текст по-моему все равно будет выходить за рамки. Вот что можно придумать?

Comment: А почему padding не решение? И как это связано с 6 дюймовыми экранами? Если размеры шрифтов фиксированы по отношению к фону, то можно ограничить количество символов в `TextView`.

Comment: Я для 5, 7 и 10 дюймовых экранов могу создать разметки и там прописать padding чтобы было нормально. Но для 6-ти дюймовых если не сделать этого (что я не хочу делать :)), то там будет как мне кажется текст накладываться на фон

Comment: Так проверьте :) По идее вообще странно получается. У Вас фон динамически расширяется в зависимости от экрана, текст тоже. Все происходит пропорционально. Просто паддингов или ограничений на количество символов должно быть достаточно.

Comment: Спасибо. Наверное выставлю ограничение текста.. Так правильнее будет.

Comment: Выставила ограничение 15 символов. Если ввожу текста больше чем 15 символов в TextView ничего не меняется. А можно ли сделать так, чтобы начальные символы стирались, а те которые ввожу добавлялись в TextView?

Comment: Эмм, ну можно `TextWatcher` повесить, выключив ограничение на количество. А в `onTextChanged` проверять превысила ли строка лимит, если да, то подменять на подстроку без первого символа. Но что-то мне подсказывает, что решение не очень

Comment: Почему? Я уже начала так делать.

Comment: Задним местом чую костылище. Но работать будет нормально

Comment: Я просто не знаю другого варианта. Если что-то посоветуете другое буду благодарна.